# How to remove newline characters from env vars with cmd only?

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, multiline

The limitation that I'm facing is that I can only use CMD for this (due to the setup of the proj).
The problem with CMD is that `for /f "tokens...` will always parse the result of `set` line by line. Meaning that an environment var with a multiline value will be parsed as 2 tokens.

Example:
`for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set') do (` will parse a multi line env var in 2 separate iterations so you can't replace the newline.

Tried things like:

```
REM Loop through the environment variables
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('set') do (
    REM Replace newline characters with spaces
    set "value=%%b"
    set "value=!value:^
    ...
```

But no success

Reproduce by:
example:

```
C:\Users\so>set NL=^
More?
More? test

C:\Users\so>set
LOGONSERVER=\\so
--other values--
NL=
test
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=20
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, clarify your specific problem or provide additional details
 to highlight exactly what you need.  As currently written,
 it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Out of curiosity, could you share an example of a multi-line environment variable in  `cmd`?

Comment: Using any other language (Python, Go, etc.) will make doing what you want trivial to implement. I'm not a `cmd` shell expert but I can't think of any way to do what you want using just `cmd` builtins.

Comment: Do you want to process all variables or only known variables? Is the content of the multi line variables in a specific format or is it arbitrary? Show samples

Comment: It is arbitrary. That's why I need a general solution. Basically going through all values.

You can create a multiline variable by:

`set NewLine=^`
then hit enter then enter a value.
I updated the question

Comment: The question is, do you know the variable names or do you need to use `set` to list them all? That's a big difference

Comment: No, I don't know the name of the variable. There can multiple variables having the problem and the variables are dynamically generated by other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the variable names, it's simple

```
@echo off
setlocal

REM *** Prepare test variable
set test_var=Line1^

Line2

echo Original:
set "test_var"
echo(
call :sanitize test_var
exit /b

:sanitize
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%=empty=%
)
FOR /F "delims=" %%V in ("%1") DO set "tmp=!%%V!"
FOR %%L in ("!LF!") DO set "sanitized=!tmp:%%~L=-LF-!"

echo Sanitized: !sanitized!
endlocal
exit /b
```

**If you list variables with the `SET` command**

Then it's tricky, because you can't know if a line starts with a variable name or with content of a multi line variable, this could be the same as a valid variable definition.

Example

> SET test
>
> test1=Line1
> test2=Line2

This could be interpreted as two variables `test1` and `test2` or it could be only one variable test1 with the content `Line1\ntest=Line2`

Therefore you need a bit more complex solution

```
@echo off
setlocal

REM *** Prepare test variable
set test1=Line1^

Line2=looks like a variable^

Line4^

=====
set test3=Line3
call :sanitize_all
exit /b

:sanitize_all
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%=empty=%
)
set "tmp=!var!"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ignoreLines=0"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%V in ('SET test') DO (
    set /a 1/ignoreLines 2> NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
      call :sanitize
    ) else (
       echo # Ignore Line: "%%V"
       set /a ignoreLines-=1
    )
  )
endlocal

exit /b

:sanitize
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%=empty=%
)
FOR /F "delims=" %%X in ("dummy") DO (
  set "varName=%%V"
  set "tmp=!%%V!"
)
FOR %%L in ("!LF!") DO set "sanitized=!tmp:%%~L=-LF-!"

REM *** This counts how many lines have to be ignored
set "ignoreLines=0"
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%L in ("!varName!=!tmp!") DO (
  set /a ignoreLines+=1
)
if !ignoreLines! GTR 0 set /a ignoreLines-=1

echo Sanitized: !varName!=!sanitized! ignore !ignoreLines! 
(
  endlocal
  set "ignoreLines=%ignoreLines%"
)
exit /b
```

This solution needs some improvements to work with any possible content.  Like variables with more than one LF or with empty content lines or lines beginning with ";"

Comment: I've got another idea to get all variable names: `for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set ^|find "="') do`  (which will still have problems when a multi-line variable contains a "=")

Comment: @Stephan It's even worse, because it complicates the `ignoreLines` counter

Comment: Yes, the main problem is that if you can't get the the key=value 's separately as cmd only works on the output of `set` and then you can't know which is a key which is a value which is simply an equal sign in a value.

Comment: @Lkf But that is exactly what my second script do, it fetch the keys separately to determine how many lines have to be skipped in the remaining output of `SET`

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately there are many special cases where the script can fail. The value can be any kind of structure.

Comment: @Lkf Show me an example where the script fails, I don't think you can find such content